# Does WS-Security require an extra signature in the SAML assertion?

Tags: saml

According to the [SAML core 2.0](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) profile, the signature, if there is one, should be right after the Issuer element (see section 2.3.3).  But in the [WS-Security 1.1.1](https://docs.oasis-open.org/wss-m/wss/v1.1.1/os/wss-SAMLTokenProfile-v1.1.1-os.html) profile, the example at section 3.5.1.4 shows a signature as the very last element in the assertion, after the Statement element.  Does this mean the assertion needs to be signed twice?  If so, how do you validate multiple signatures covering the same XML?